# Check that data in a SQL table already exists

Tags: php, sql, linux, database

I want to log what a user enters into a PHP form, and make sure they are not entering data that already exists in a database table.

I have the code already that enters the data into the table from user input, but I'm not sure how to check for duplicates. For example I want to check that there is no product under the same name being added again.

This is what I have so far:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (product_name, code, comments)
        VALUES ('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[code]','$_POST[comments]')";
```

Comment: Your query is open to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What you have so far is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: This is horrendously open to sql injection - but aside from that you need to read up on `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is **terrible** SQL coding practice and, as stated before, is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks but something along these lines should work.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO user_date 
    SELECT 
        product_name = '$_POST[product_name]'
        ,code = '$_POST[code]'
        ,comments = '$_POST[comments]'
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE product_name = '$_POST[product_name]') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by adding a uniqueness constraint to your table itself. This way you can prevent duplicate records from being added.

In your case I would go with this:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_data` ADD UNIQUE (
`product_name`
)
```

Also, you could check for the record before you add it:

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) AS number FROM user_data WHERE product_name LIKE '".$_POST['product_name']."'";
```

If the column "number" 1 (or bigger), you know it already exists. Also when you get 2, or bigger, you will know that you already have duplicate records.